# single line - no indentation break before and after

Tags: paragraphs

What's the easiest way to have a line not indented and with a break before and after?

Example:

> Following the list of ingredients:
>
> - carrots
> - ...

The Latex-Code would be:

```
Following the list of ingredients:

\begin{enumerate}
    \item carrots
    \item ...
\end{enumerate}
```

By default the line would be indented and without preceeding line break.

Any suggestions for a short-macro to have single lines?

I sometimes use

```
\ \\ Following the list of ingredients:
```

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you want.

Comment: The line "Following.." is being indented as a usual paragraph's first line. I don't want this line to be indentes as it is only a single line introducing the following list.

Comment: Does `\noindent` before `Following...` solve your issue?

Comment: @PeterGrill: Yes, but it doesn't cause a line break before and after `Following`. So far I used `\ \\ Following` but don't know if this is a nice way/solution.

Comment: Ok, not that it is clearer, I have updated my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** Based on comments

I'd suggest using `\bigskip`, `\medskip` or `\smallskip` along with `\noindent`. This will allow you to control the amount of spacing you want. Since you were looking for a `\shortmacro` I have added that as well.  Using a macro is a good ideas as that help to ensure that your spacing in these kinds of situations is consistent, and allows you to adjust all the sapcing in one spot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\shortmacro}{\bigskip\noindent}%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%
\shortmacro Following the list of ingredients:
%
\begin{itemize}[align=left]
    \item carrots
    \item ...
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\lipsum` package as added just to include some dummy text so that we could see the spacing.

Comment: I don't want to change the space between the items.

Comment: Solution has been totally re-written. Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the re-written solution!
Solves my problem largely.
I just wonder how to get a spacing of the height of a text line.

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to the line `Following the list of ingredients:` that you want to have

- no indent; and
- a break before

you can do the following:

- Prefix the line with `\noindent`. This avoids the paragraph indent `\parindent` for that specific paragraph.
- Add a blank line before the sentence so TeX will see it as a new paragraph. This inserts a vertical skip between the two paragraphs of size `\parskip`. Depending on your document class, this may be virtually unnoticeable. You can modify this value using `\setlength{\parskip}{<len>` where `<len>` is any [recognized length unit](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-86.html).

The (very small) [`parskip` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) actually provides all of these requirements. Or, if you're interested, view the package [`parskip.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/parskip/parskip.sty) file.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem is that you don't want a paragraph break between your text and list. TeX treats a blank line as a 'new paragraph' mark. So try

```
Following the list of ingredients:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item carrots
    \item ...
\end{enumerate}
```

or 'comment out' the extra line

```
Following the list of ingredients:
%
\begin{enumerate}
    \item carrots
    \item ...
\end{enumerate}
```

as TeX will then treat it as 'not there'.

Comment: Then the line "Following ..." is still being indented as it is handled like a new paragraph's first line.

Comment: @Sebastian If it starts a paragraph, and the rest of the document uses an indent for paragraph first lines, then traditionally it should still be indented. As Peter has said, you can use `\noindent` to prevent this, but do consider your overall document design.

Comment: Well, I think a line with only a few words which is indented and stands before a list looks odd.. But for a long text it's right and nice to have the first line of a paragraph indented and without line breaks.