# Avoid indenting one-liner paragraphs

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

Some weeks ago I've found here a thread about how to accomplish not indenting paragraphs when they consists on only one line. I can't find this thread now.

What I want is that `\parindent` only applies to paragraphs with two or more lines, the same as issuing `\noindent` before those one-liner paragraphs but in an automatic way.

Comment: Hi! Why would you want that? I can't see a reason for this behavior, and I think that if I understood what it's meant for maybe I could suggest something else to do instead.

Comment: Sometimes if "paragraphs" are short (one line) they look ugly with indentation and I add `\noindent` to remove its indentation leaving all paragraphs with normal indentation. I saw a question about that with more than one answer. Now I want to implement it and can't find the thread...

Comment: A style that indents paragraphs is often used in conjunction with no extra vertical space before a paragraph. In that case, no indentation would make a one-line paragraph no longer be recognisable. Just a caveat.

Comment: @ChristianLindig yes, sure, thanks; however I'm removing the indentation with caution... Sometimes I start an `itemize` or `enumerate` environment with just before a paragraph describing what these items are; this paragraph is usually one line. Also I'm writing a DTX file and almost on every `\DescribeMacro` I put `\noindent`before.

Comment: You say "with caution", but that doesn't apply to the automatic solution you are asking for, right? Will your one-liner be recognizable as a paragraph if the previous paragraph happens to end with a full line?

If the short text before your `itemize` is like a header for it, maybe you could make it into `\paragraph{...}` instead? (Regardless of whether it fits on a line or is slightly longer.)

Comment: @EmilioLazo: Are you looking for http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30280/single-line-no-indentation-break-before-and-after?

Comment: Think about what these lines are semantically or functionally and define a command for them. If you are using them as titles for lists, then do \newcommand{\listheader}[1]{\noindent #1\par} .

Comment: @pst Yes, an automatic solution generally isn't used with caution. If the previous paragraphs ends with a full line the new one-liner won't be recognized, right! unless I set a higher `\parskip`.... I did mention the `itemize` environment as an example; what I have in mind isn't restricted to describing what the following `itemize` or `enumerate` is. I'm sorry for the late response!

Comment: @Jake thanks, but it isn't :-( I don't understand why I can't find it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to wrap your document in a \vbox, the following seems to work. (So, this is only good for one page.)

```
\vbox{\let\Par=\par
      \parindent=20pt
      \def\par{\Par
               \ifnum  \prevgraf=1 
                  \setbox0=\lastbox  
                  \nointerlineskip
                  \moveleft \parindent\copy0    \fi}%

    One line.

    Two lines blah    blah  
    blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  
    blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  
    blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  
    blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  
    blah  blah  blah  blah  blah  

         }

        \bye
```

"\prevgraf" is a primitive TeX integer variable that gives the number of lines in the last, or current, paragraph.

"\lastbox" is another primitive command that removes the last \vbox or \hbox on the current vertical or horizontal list and this box then becomes the \lastbox. It can't be used in vertical mode but can be used in internal vertical mode; hence the need to wrap things in a vbox.

I don't know if something similar, using \prevgraf, can be done in vertical mode.

The above was intended for Plain TeX, but it should work anywhere as it uses only primitive control sequences (I think).

Comment: Thank you. It worked also in LaTeX. Can't be extended to be breakable in pages? Defining an environment in which the whole document can be wrapped, perhaps?

Comment: @EmilioLazo This should work: \setbox1=\vbox{ stuff in vbox above }  \unvbox1 (This is a bit silly IMO :) ) You might want to use an unused box register  though: \newbox\Mybox  \setbox\Mybox = ...